# What code do I have to input at the end of You Have to Win the Game?

Tags: you-have-to-win-the-game

At the end of the game *You Have to Win the Game*, a code needs to be entered to win. I have already found the secret word:

> **VXSHU**

and the secret symbol

> Apparently a **3** rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise

I tried inputting the secret word directly and applying ROT13 and then inputting it, and neither worked. So, what is the code and how am I supposed to figure it out?

Comment: Would this be the game you just lost when I mentioned it?  ;-)

Comment: Actually, it's a free platformer on Steam.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The secret symbol means that each letter should be moved back by 3, so the cypher is effectively ROT(-3). This means that the final secret word is

> **SUPER**

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the secret code

> SUPER

and it worked. Just a note: When you win the game, the game puts you back at the first screen, but you still have all of your powers and progress. But when you choose to lose the game, however, the game puts you back at the first screen and you lose all of your powers.

Answer (score -1):

I just finished the game after 2:26:53 It took me so long cause I tried three times before and I was confused so I made a flow chart to keep track of where I was! The code was

> Super

Also I was only 80.86% done, cause I didn't find everything, but it was too stressful so I'm not going to find them!